# How to get nearest PositionComponent in a good way?

Tags: position, flame

I have a "player" and several "enemy" beside:

[image]

Now I just use a loop to get every distance:

```dart
  void fireBullet() {
    var enemies = gameRef.children.whereType<Enemy>();

    if (enemies.isEmpty) return;

    PositionComponent nearestEnemy = enemies.first;

    enemies.forEach((element) {
      if (element.distance(playerComponent) < nearestEnemy.distance(playerComponent)) {
        nearestEnemy = element;
      }
    });

    // fire bullet to enemy
  }
```

I think it's not the best solution. If there's too many enemy, performance will degrade.

Is there any better way to get nearest PositionComponent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no better built-in method unfortunately.

There are a few improvements that you can do to your game though that will make a big performance difference:

- Use `distance2`, because then it won't have to do a square root operation behind the scenes.
- Save the last `distance` calculation to avoid doing it twice.
- Use `query` instead of `whereType` (the query is cached).

So it would be something like this:

```dart
  void fireBullet() {
    var enemies = gameRef.children.query<Enemy>();

    if (enemies.isEmpty) return;

    var nearestEnemy = enemies.first;
    var nearestDistance = nearestEnemy.position.distance2(playerComponent);

    enemies.forEach((element) {
      final distance = element.position.distance2(playerComponent.position);
      if (distance < distanceNearest) {
        nearestEnemy = element;
        nearestDistance = distance;
      }
    });

    // fire bullet to enemy
  }
```

I believe that you would have other performance issues before you hit performance issues with this code in the updated state.